# Ag grid selectionChanged event not working

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I am facing issue with "selectionChanged" event in ag-grid(Angular)
Scenario is that let suppose we have two pages on different routes , first page we have grid without "selectionChanged" event and another one have grid with "selectionChanged" event then when our screen on first page and click on any row and then redirect to another route page from menu bar(have "selectionChanged" event) but we can't click "selectionChanged" event not working.

Comment: Can you explain more . and share some code example where you get stucks too ?

Comment: Yes, please show some code so that we can help you better